# Get a string list of values from a generic object

Tags: java, json, reflection

So I have an Object that comes in that can be any of 100 different specific objects, with different elements inside it, from other objects, lists, sequences, primitives etc.

I want to strip the values in a depth first fashion to make a string of simple values with a delimiter between them. I have mapped the fields and stored them elsewhere using recursion/reflection that only happens once a new Object type comes in for the first time.

An example of how I'm storing the data in the database for a few simple example objects:

```
Object A layout table: Timestamp = 12345 Fields = Length|Width|Depth 
Object B layout table: Timestamp = 12345 Fields = Height|Weight|Name
Object A layout table: Timestamp = 12350 Fields = Length|Width|Depth|Label 

Object A sample: Timestamp = 12348 Values = 5|7|2 
Object A sample: Timestamp = 12349 Values = 4|3|1 
Object B sample: Timestamp = 12346 Values = 75|185|Steve Irwin
Object A sample: Timestamp = 12352 Values = 7|2|8|HelloWorld
```

Below is my current solution. I'm seeking improvements or alternatives to the design to accomplish the goal stated above.

Currently I get the object in and translate it to JSON using gson.toJson(); From that, I cycle through the JSON to get values using the code below. Issue is, this code is very CPU intensive on the low end CPU I am developing for due to the fact that there are many samples coming in per second. Overall purpose of the application is a data recorder that records real time samples into a SQLite database. I have also attempted to store the unmodified JSON into a SQLite BLOB column, but this is terribly inefficient with regards to DB size. Is there a better/more efficient method for getting values out of an object?

I don't have an issue storing the field mapping since it only needs to be done once, but the value stripping needs to be done for every sample. I know you can do it via reflection as well, but that is also processing heavy. Anyone have a better method?

```
public static List<String> stripValuesFromJson(JsonElement json)
{
    // Static array list that will have the values added to it. This will
    // be the return object
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Iterate through the JSONElement and start parsing out values
    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : ((JsonObject) json).entrySet())
    {
        // Call the recursive processor that will parse out items based on their individual type: primitive, array, seq etc
        dataList.addAll(dataParser(entry.getValue()));
    }

    return dataList;
}

/**
 * The actual data processor that parses out individual values and deals with every possible type of data that can come in.
 * 
 * @param json - The json object being recursed through
 * @return - return the list of values
 */
public static List<String> dataParser(JsonElement json)
{
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList<String>();

    // Deal with primitives
    if (json instanceof JsonPrimitive)
    {
        // Deal with items that come up as true/false.
        if (json.getAsString().equals("false"))
        {
            dataList.add("0");
        } else if (json.getAsString().equals("true"))
        {
            dataList.add("1");
        } else
        {
            dataList.add(json.getAsString());
        }
        // Send through recursion to get the primitives or objects out of this object
    } else if (json instanceof JsonObject)
    {
        dataList.addAll(stripValuesFromJson(json));
    } else if (json instanceof JsonArray)
    {
        // Send through recursion for each element in this array/sequence
        for (JsonElement a : (JsonArray) json)
        {
            dataList.addAll(dataParser(a));
        }
    } else if (json instanceof JsonNull)
    {
        dataList.add(null);
    } else
    {
        errorLog.error("Unknown JSON type: " + json.getClass());
    }

    return dataList;
}
```

Comment: One thing you could improve is pass `List<String> dataList` to `stripValuesFromJson` and `dataParser`. You will then add values to this list and pass this list recursively to `stripValuesFromJson` again. This will save you creating new array lists here and there.

Comment: I also don't quite understand how list of values (without keys) may be useful.

Comment: Apart from minor things, I think you can't process a parsed JSON object much more efficiently.

Comment: As I said above, this is for storing in a database (a blob because the DB needs to be generic so that if the layout changes the DB doesn't need rebuilt - basically Timestamp column, data BLOB column). I store the key layout in one table and I want to store the samples with just values in another. The purpose being so that I can get the database smaller so each sample doesn't have the keys in them as there are infinitely more samples than a single key layout.

Comment: I'm even willing to use something that is not JSON if I could fetch the values in a more efficient manner, but since it is a generic Object, I need to go to some common format before stripping the values out.

Comment: I still don't get it. Is key layout fixed? Do all samples have the same key layout? Or is there some relatively small set of key layouts and all samples have to conform to one of them?

Comment: Objects are fixed for a given time. But may change at some point. So the layouts that are stored have a timestamp. When a layout changes a new layout is written to the DB table with a new timestamp. So when retrieving samples of that data type, the client must fetch the sample, get the timestamp of that sample and refer to the valid layout from the layout table for that Object type at a given time to match up the key from the layout table with the value from the sample.

Comment: So maybe instead of sending structured JSON, simply send JSON only containing identification of the key layout and values as an array?

Comment: Object A layout table: TS = 12345 Keys = Length|Width|Depth
Object A layout table: TS = 12350 Keys = Length|Width|Depth|Label
Object A sample: TS = 12348 Values = 5|7|2
Object A sample: TS = 12349 Values = 4|3|1
Object A sample: TS = 12352 Values = 7|2|8|HelloWorld

Comment: Please edit your question, code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: I added the changes to the OP. TS is timestamp. Gave examples of how two different (in this case simple) objects are stored in a combined table of samples with different layouts and the layout keys are stored in the layout table but change over time.

Comment: And JSON for these samples would look like?

Comment: Honestly the JSON is irrelevant it's just used as a possible common format for fetching the values, the end goal would be the example above. I use reflection to find the layout for the layout table. The main purpose of all of this is that you have an Object (that you don't know the contents/elements/types of) and you need to get values out of it and store said values. How I get to the end goal from the beginning doesn't matter in this application. So simplest terms, the keys are fields in the objects, and values are their values in a 1 to 1 order.

Comment: To be honest, this starts looking like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Looks pretty strange to me.

Comment: The first two paragraphs of the question state the overall goal. The rest is explaining how I am currently accomplishing it and other ways I know of doing it that can't work in my CPU limited environment. So I'm searching for alternatives or improvements to the existing solution that I have. I edited the OP to clarify what I am asking.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could try out is writing your own JSON parser which simply emits values. I have more experience in [JavaCC](https://javacc.org/) so I'd take [one of existing](https://github.com/RobertFischer/json-parser) JSON grammars and modify it so that it only outputs values. This should not be too complicated.
Take for example the `booleanValue` production from the [mentioned grammar](https://github.com/RobertFischer/json-parser/blob/master/src/main/javacc/com/smokejumperit/json/parser/JSONParser.jj):

```
Boolean booleanValue(): {
    Boolean b;
}{
    (
        (
            <TRUE>
            { b = Boolean.TRUE; }
        ) | (
            <FALSE>
            { b = Boolean.FALSE; }
        )   
    )
    { return b; }
}
```

Basically you will need to replace returning the boolean value with appending `"1"` or `"0"` to the target list.

[ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/) is another option.